# How to change dropdown menu button title, by selecting item?

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, search, dropdown

I need to change title of dropdown when I select item in the dropdown list, this is my code for now

```
<div class="btn-group">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data- 
toggle="dropdown">
Option: <span class="selection">Groups</span><span class="caret"></span>
 </button>
 <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
  <li><a href="#">Group 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Group 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Group 3</a></li>
 </ul>
 </div>
```

and this is jQuery

```
$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){

 $(this).parents(".btn-group").find('.selection').text($(this).text());
 $(this).parents(".btn-group").find('.selection').val($(this).text());

});
```

Still doesn't change my title when I select any of these.

Comment: Your code works fine. It changes the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your `<head>`:

```
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

Maybe you forgot to include the JQuery library.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i understood your issue is that you want to change the text of the button with the clicking linked text, if so you can try this one: http://jsbin.com/owuyix/4/edit

```
 $(function(){

    $(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){

      $(".btn:first-child").text($(this).text());
      $(".btn:first-child").val($(this).text());

   });

});
```

As per your comment:

this doesn't work for me when I have lists item `<li>` populated through ajax call.

so you have to delegate the event to the closest static parent with `.on()` jQuery method:

```
 $(function(){

    $(".dropdown-menu").on('click', 'li a', function(){
      $(".btn:first-child").text($(this).text());
      $(".btn:first-child").val($(this).text());
   });

});
```

Here event is delegated to static parent `$(".dropdown-menu")`, although you can delegate the event to the `$(document)` too because it is always available.